# PowerShell Discord Webhook

Tags: powershell, discord

I am getting an error while using this code

```
$uri = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/760116538895499265/yhQdNc10asfDzt8hldAJp32et1Gp_1-mvqIGPWZiAMcOwFjb5aqf7uNEF7MX6i15UKJK"

$hash = @{ "content" = "heyyy"; }

$JSON = $hash | convertto-json

Invoke-WebRequest -uri $uri -Method POST -Body $JSON
```

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}
At line:7 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -uri $uri -Method POST -Body $JSON
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

what is this due to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the Content-Type to application/json in the request:

```
 Invoke-WebRequest -uri $uri -Method POST -Body $JSON -Headers @{'Content-Type' = 'application/json'}
```

See: https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1210

Comment: Do you know how can I adapt this to send a file please? :D